# Shopping for French Doors

Tags: doors

I currently have a sliding door that is 60X96.  I want to replace it with french doors.  I'm looking at DIY and am wondering whether to go used or new.  I was hoping to stay at 500 or less, which makes me thing used.  Any thoughts?

Comment: That's an odd dimension for the height.  You're sure it's not 80"?

Comment: Yes, positive.  Those are the dimensions.  New options definitely exist, but I've been looking for used options for about 6 months.

Answer (score 1):

Is this an exterior or interior door?

If it's exterior, I'd recommend going with new so you get a good weather seal.

For an interior door, if you can find a good quality used door in a style you like, I don't see a significant disadvantage to getting a used one other than the trouble of making sure it's mounted correctly on the hinges.  If the door frame is included, you'll want to be sure the depth is the same and that it hasn't been cut too short for your flooring.